# Wave equation solution with constant zero.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation

Suppose $u \in C_{x, t}^2([0, 1] \times [0, \infty))$, and $u$ is solution of following equation: $$ \begin{cases}u_{tt} = u_{xx} \\ u|_{\partial[0, 1]} = 0\end{cases}$$

If $u \not\equiv 0 $, could it be that for some fixed $x_0 \in [0, 1],$ $u(x_0, t) = 0$ for any $t \in [0, \infty]$?

Answer: (by @Paul) Yes, $u(x, t) = \sin(2\pi t)\sin(2\pi x)$.

Editted question: Could it be that for some fixed interval $[a, b] \subset [0, 1]$, $u(x, t) = 0$, for any $x \in [a, b],$ and $t \in [0, \infty]$?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking.  If $u$ is not constant, then by definition it is nonzero at some point.  Plus, this isn't well-posed.  The wave equation needs initial conditions.  You could have a sine wave initial condition with the Dirichlet boundary conditions that does satisfy the equation.

Comment: It doesn't matter, though your argumentation makes sense. It is solution of equation wroted in question and that is it. Question is could $u(x, t)$ be equal to zero in some fixed point $x_0$ everytime.

Comment: Question was editted. Thank you for link anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  $u= sin ( 2\pi t) sin( 2\pi x)$ is just such a solution.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind a embarassing, thank you after all!

Comment: Prepared some related question though.